# Is there any way to get the (actual) RECT of the windows 11 Notification Center?

Tags: winapi, rust, windows-11

I am currently writing an application in Rust that tries to fix issues with top-aligned taskbars on windows 11 (as this behavior is not officially supported).
I'm moving windows around to match what they should look like on a top-aligned taskbar, but I'm starting to get some trouble with the Notification Center.

The Notification center **window** has a fixed height that spans from top to bottom of the desktop. The notification center does not match this actual height.
Is there any way to get the actual "interactable" RECT of the notification center in windows 11 using Windows APIs?

I've tried the GetClientRect and GetWindowRect methods, but these don't help me in any way, as the actual rendered window has a different height.

I'm pretty much looking for *any* way to properly align the notification center items from top-to-bottom instead of bottom-to-top.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your program [DPI aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process)?

Comment: According to the Doc:[GetWindowRect function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect)

In conformance with conventions for the RECT structure, the bottom-right coordinates of the returned rectangle are exclusive. GetWindowRect is virtualized for DPI. I suggest you could try to use [DwmGetWindowAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute), specifying DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS.

Comment: Ive tried DPI awareness but it did not change anything. I'll try DwnGetWindowAttribute tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it. Still get the full height.